# Love.plot - display balance for a second set of weights

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching, weighting

I have the following data:

```
library(MatchIt)
library(cobalt)

data("lalonde")
```

and created weights:

```
formula <- treat ~ age + educ + married + nodegree

# Calculate PS
propensity_model <- matchit(formula, data = lalonde, method = NULL, distance = 'glm', link = 'logit')

# Store PS
propensity_score <- propensity_model$distance

# Calculate IPW
ipw <- ifelse(lalonde$treat == 1, 1 / propensity_score, 1 / (1 - propensity_score))

# Calculate MW
mw <- ifelse(lalonde$treat == 1, min(propensity_score, 1 - propensity_score) / propensity_score, min(propensity_score, 1 - propensity_score) / (1 - propensity_score))

# Store weights 
weighted_data <- lalonde
weighted_data$mw <- mw
weighted_data$ipw <- ipw
```

Now I want to create a `love.plot` to assess balance of unadjusted, `ipw` and `mw` as follows:

```
# Store weights
mw_weights <- weighted_data$mw
ipw_weights <- weighted_data$ipw

# Create the love.plot
love.plot(treat ~ age + educ + married + nodegree,
          data = weighted_data, estimand = "ATE",
          binary = "std",
          stats = c("mean.diffs"),
          weights = list(w1 = mw_weights, 
                         w2 = ipw_weights),
          var.order = "unadjusted",
          abs = TRUE,
          line = FALSE, 
          thresholds = c(m = .1),
          #var.names = new.names,
          colors = c("red", "blue", "darkgreen"),
          shapes = c("triangle filled", "circle filled", "square filled"),
          sample.names = c("Unweighted", "MW", "IPW"),
          limits = list(m = c(0, 1.0)),
          wrap = 20,
          position = "top")
```

The result shows just unadjusted and `ipw` and I do not know why `mw` is missing

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it is just possible using a `WeightIt`  object? Then I would have to create manual weights using `WeightIt`  - using `as.weightit` ? How to do that?

Comment: `mw` is not missing, it is just superposed to IPW

Comment: @Maël HA! Thank you. Why is that?

Comment: I don't know the data, but it seems to be giving the same results for both weigths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you made a mistake in calculating the matching weights. The correct code is

```
mw <- ifelse(lalonde$treat == 1,
             pmin(propensity_score, 1 - propensity_score) / propensity_score,
             pmin(propensity_score, 1 - propensity_score) / (1 - propensity_score))
```

You have to use `pmin()` instead of `min()` to return a vector; `min()` returns a single value, so it finds the smallest single value of `c(propensity_score, 1 - propensity_score)` and applies that to everyone. When using `pmin()`, the matching weights are calculated correctly and both sets of SMDs appear in the plot.

Note that you can use `WeightIt` to compute the weights directly, either by using `weightit()` to estimate weights or `get_w_from_ps()` to compute weights from supplied propensity scores.

Comment: Superb! Using MWs corresponds to the ATE with clinical equipoise - so SMDs imo need to be calculated using s.d.denom = "pooled" pre- and post matching, right?

Comment: You can calculate SMDs however you want. "pooled" seems like a natural choice and is the default. I would also avoid MWs and use overlap weights instead [(M&Z 2020)](http://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01388).